# En mi app de android studio aparece todo gris

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Lo unico que he agregado es un fondo y quitado la status bar y la de notificaciones.. El problema es que no muestra ningun error solo al correr la app en un telefono fisico aparece en gris la pantalla no muestra ni el fondo ni botones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que estas realizando, de otra forma estaríamos adivinando, te sugiero revisar [ask], edita tu pregunta y agrega detalles saludos.

Comment: Podrias responerme? ya edite mi pregunta como marca